# ctrl+alt+b command using build package in atom returns the following error:

Tags: miktex, atom, l3build

Platform: win32; texpath:
Processing file MA Report.tex (Modelling and Analysis 1D Report) in directory C:\Users\jyk\Documents\Report
latexmk builder
latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "Modelling and Analysis 1D Report.tex"
Parsing C:\Users\jyk\Documents\2D\Report.log
Could not read log file!

Any suggestion on how to fix this? It's my first time using Latex and Latex in Atom

Comment: There seems to be something strange with the file name: "MA Report", "Modelling and Analysis 1D Report" (sic), and "Report" are all appearing as possible file names.  Could you try renaming to a filename without spaces and see if that works?

Comment: Heyy, thanks for the help! I did that and it was able to run without any errors. Although, when I tried opening the report.pdf file (pdf-viewer package installed), it returned the error saying Report.pdf files is not a pdf file??

Comment: Does this work if you run `pdflatex` on your tex file from the command line?